# Javascript add class on scroll with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, settimeout, onscroll

I'm having some trouble with adding a class when a specified class is scrolled into view with a delay between when the classes are added.

I have three divs, all side by side, all with the class fadeInDownScroll seen in the javascript code.

The onScrollReach function works, and the class fadeInDown is added when reached on scroll, but all three of the divs have this added at the same time.

Below is the javascript code I've been trying to get to work:

```
function onScrollReach(selector, classToBeAdded, offset, delayTime, callback) {
    var didScroll = false;
    var this_top;
    var height;
    var top;

    //If no offset, set one as 0 so that its initialised
    if(!offset) { var offset = 0; } 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        didScroll = true;
    });
    //Set interval of a tenth of a second, so this will trigger 10 times a second
    setInterval(function() {
        //If they've scrolled within the last 1/10th of a second
        if (didScroll) {

        //Prevent retrigger by setting false
        didScroll = false;
        //Get scroll height
        top = $(this).scrollTop();
        //For each of the selector element (class you're looking for)
        $(selector).each(function(i){
            //Set position of where on page you want it to trigger the event
            this_top = $(this).offset().top - offset;
            height   = $(this).height();

            // Scrolled within current section & doesn't already have the class
            if (top >= this_top && !$(this).hasClass(classToBeAdded)) {
            //=$(this).addClass(classToBeAdded);

            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(delayTime * (i / 2));
                console.log('class added');
                $(this).addClass(classToBeAdded);
            }, 100);
            //You can call it with a function so tha tyou can do something else straight after
            //This only applies if thats the case
            if (typeof callback == "function") callback(selector);
            }
        });
        }
    }, 100);
}

//Target Class, Class to be added, Offset for scroll, Delay Time
onScrollReach(".fadeInDownScroll", "fadeInDown", 600, 3000, '');
```

I know this is a subject that there are a lot of similar posts, however after reading through a lot of these I could not find one that solved this exact issue

Comment: A few code smells here.  First off, having an interval to tell if the user scrolled seem odd, as you have a scroll event handler.  Secondly, `this_top` and `height` in your each loop are not scoped to the closure.  So they are going to be the same for every selector you iterate over.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the comment, I'm new to Javascript so I may have quite a few things that could be improved. I went for the setInterval on scroll after reading this: https://benmarshall.me/attaching-javascript-handlers-to-scroll-events/ . Can you give me any further explanation about the closure comment? I'm struggling to see why they would be the same if they're within an each function referencing 'this'

Comment: Bump - anyone have any more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code

```
function onScrollReach(selector, classToBeAdded, offset, delayTime, callback) {
    var didScroll = false;
    var this_top;
    var height;
    var top;

    //If no offset, set one as 0 so that its initialised
    if(!offset) { var offset = 0; } 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        didScroll = true;
    });
    //Set interval of a tenth of a second, so this will trigger 10 times a second
    setInterval(function() {
        //If they've scrolled within the last 1/10th of a second
        if (didScroll) {

        //Prevent retrigger by setting false
        didScroll = false;
        //Get scroll height
        top = $(this).scrollTop();
        //For each of the selector element (class you're looking for)
            //Set position of where on page you want it to trigger the event
            this_top = $(this).offset().top - offset;
            height   = $(this).height();

            // Scrolled within current section & doesn't already have the class
            if (top >= this_top && !$(this).hasClass(classToBeAdded)) {
            //=$(this).addClass(classToBeAdded);

            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('class added');
                $(selector).addClass(classToBeAdded);
            }, 100);
            //You can call it with a function so tha tyou can do something else straight after
            //This only applies if thats the case
            if (typeof callback == "function") callback(selector);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}

//Target Class, Class to be added, Offset for scroll, Delay Time
onScrollReach(".fadeInDownScroll", "fadeInDown", 600, 3000, '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. All three divs all still had the new class added onto them at the same time. Please, can you explain why you've taken out the each on this one? The reason I've got the each included is so that I can use this class on other divs on the same page, without triggering the class being added to every one of the divs the first time the class is scrolled to